# How to access the wp_footer function and edit his content?

Tags: wordpress

I have a script that is being executed by wp_footer function. In my footer.php page, at the bottom, we can see the final of the first script, and under the ctrl+u, (html source code), we can see the result, the both scripts, one after anoter. How to access the wp_footer function and edit his content?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQc9o.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL5aM.jpg)

Comment: Here the anoter print

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/whppuvql9/

Answer (score 0):

I saw that there were a plugin "Script N Styles" with some bug, that was not appearing that script inserted in that page. I tried to deactivate and activate, remove and install again, install older versions, but nothing happens. So I just removed the plugin and copied the script manually and inserted into footer.php.

Answer (score 0):

go to functions.php file folder of your wordpress and just scroll to wp_footer function. Now you can edit it.